# siunitx & makecell in tables: number alignment does not work

Tags: tables, siunitx, makecell

I want to align my numbers with `siunitx`, but in combination with `makecell` it produce several error message based on my `\makecell` commands. I tried to protect my `makecell` commands with brackets, but it still does not work.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{booktabs} %Table format
\usepackage{makecell} %Connected rows
\usepackage{siunitx} %Number alignment

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\small
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{tabular}{scc}
\toprule
\makecell{\textbf{A} \\ {[min]}} &
\makecell{\textbf{B} \\ {[\%]}} &
\makecell{\textbf{C} \\ {[\%]}} \\
\midrule
0.0 & 20.0 & 45.0 \\
8.0 & 29.0 & 45.0 \\
15.0 & 10.0 & 90.0 \\
20.0 & 15.0 & 90.0 \\
20.1 & 55.0 & 45.0 \\
30.0 & 55.0 & 45.0 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `\makecell` had to be inside curly braces. also column type is `S`, not `s`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

in `S` column type `S` texts (usual in column headers) had to be enclosed in curly braces, even if they are in `\makecell` or `\thead` macros form `makecell` package. exception is, if the header is inside `\multicolumn` cells.

your table should be for example as follows below:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{booktabs} %Table format
\usepackage{makecell} %Connected rows
\usepackage{siunitx} %Number alignment

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\centering
\small
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{tabular}{*{3}{S[table-format=2.1]}}
    \toprule
{\makecell{\textbf{A} \\ {[min]}}} &
{\makecell{\textbf{B} \\ {[\%]}}}  &
{\makecell{\textbf{C} \\ {[\%]}}} \\
\midrule
 0.0 & 20.0 & 45.0 \\
 8.0 & 29.0 & 45.0 \\
15.0 & 10.0 & 90.0 \\
20.0 & 15.0 & 90.0 \\
20.1 & 55.0 & 45.0 \\
30.0 & 55.0 & 45.0 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```